# .NET MVC ViewからControllerへのbootstrap toggleを用いて選択状態を渡すには

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap

VIEW側で下記のようなbootstrapを用いたトグルボタンを作成しました。
このトグルボタンの選択状況(ON/OFF)をトグルの切り替わり時にControllerに渡したいのですがどのように実装すればいいでしょうか。

ソースを一部記載致します。

※Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var test = Request.Form["cbOnOff"];

        return View();
    }
```

※View

```
 <div style="width: 200px; display:inline-flex;">

    @Html.CheckBox("cbOnOff", true, new
    {
        data_toggle = "toggle",
        data_size = "small",
        data_on = "ON",
        data_off = "OFF"
    })
 </div>
```

※実行時のページソース(チェックボックス部分)

```
<div style="width: 200px; display:inline-flex;">
    <input checked="checked" data-off="OFF" data-on="ON" data-size="small" data-toggle="toggle" id="cbOnOff" name="cbOnOff" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="cbOnOff" type="hidden" value="false" />
</div>
```

のようになっていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScriptで値が変化する際のイベント(`onlick`など)を監視し、AJAXと呼ばれる手法でリクエストを送信し、結果を受け取ることができます。ASP.NET MVCの場合はjQueryを使用して

```
<script>
    $("#cbOnOff").click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("アクション名")',
            data: { checked: e.target.checked },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(d)
            {
                // 何らかの処理
            },
            error: function(er)
            {
                // エラー処理
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

のようなスクリプトを記述すれば、コントローラー側で

```
ActionResult アクション名(bool checked);
```

のようなアクションを定義して状態を受け取ることができます。通常はアクションでJSONを返却し、JavaScriptのコールバック関数へとさらに処理が続くことなります。

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NETの標準的な方法では、同名の`<input type="hidden" />`をチェックボックスより後ろに配置し、`checkbox`に`True`、`hidden`に`False`を指定します。

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbOnOff" value="True" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbOnOff" value="False" />
```

このようなHTMLで`Request.Form["cbOnOff"]`に`True`または`False`が必ず送信されるようになり、アクションの`bool`型引数でバインドすることができます。

```
ActionResult SomeAction(bool cbOnOff);
```

なお上記のようなHTMLは`@Html.CheckBoxFor`または`CheckBox`拡張メソッドで出力するのが便利です。

```
@Html.CheckBox("cbOnOff", true, new{
    data_toggle="toggle",
    data_size="small",
    data_on="ON",
    data_off="OFF" })
```

### 追記

上の例では`CheckBox`メソッドを使用していますが、これは`CheckBoxFor`より制約が緩く説明が簡単になるからです。実際に記述する場合は型指定されたビューで`CheckBoxFor`を利用すべきです。

また前提として`<input>`要素が値を送信するのは`<form>`内で`<button type="submit">`その他の要因でサブミットが発生した場合です。ASP.NET MVCであれば通常は`@using(Html.BeginForm()){}`のブロック内に記述してください。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。上記2パターンを試してみましたが、どちらもnullが返ってきてしまいます。何か原因として考えられることはあるでしょうか？

Comment: @TSaito 前提として上記の例ではパラメーターが`bool`型のため、絶対に`null`となることはありません。とりあえずブラウザーのフォームパラメーターにパラメーター`cbOnOff`が含まれているかと`Request.Form`で値を認識しているかを確認してみてください。おそらくチェックボックスがフォーム外にあるとか、バインディングパスが一致していないとか、cbOnOff以外の要因で*null*となっているとかそんなところだと思います。

Comment: @pgrho様 Request.Fo‌​rmで値は認識されていませんでした。別途回答欄にソースを記載しました。お手数をおかけしますがご確認いただけますでしょうか。